# How to exchange/remove/overwrite a PDF's background?

Tags: pdf, convert

as the title says I want to change background of a PDF. This are some slides, and to save toner I thought it would be good to change the background to white. I tried pdftk with its operations: background and stamp, but the don't work as expected:

```
pdftk old.pdf background white.pdf output out.pdf
pdftk old.pdf stamp white.pdf output out.pdf
```

I also tried convert (bloating my pdf upto 200MB) as done this way:

```
convert old.pdf -background white new.pdf
```

with no luck. Do you know a way I could perform this?

Answer (score 2):

To deal with these presentations, I used a few times [Sun PDF Import Extension](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/pdfimport). When installed, you are able to import PDF presentations with OpenOffice.org Impress. Even though the conversion is not 100% smooth, you are able to edit the background and change the color. It may be a bit tedious if you are dealing with lots of slides, but it's the best solution I found for these cases. You should note that everything is converted into Impress' objects.

Comment: lol got there first, while I was typing my answer =D. BTW, do not open the PDF in impress, open it it writer for better results.

Comment: Ahh its about 260 slides in one file (27MB)! openoffice tries to load, but it takes ages. What I try next is to, split the pdf into 50 pages chunks,... and retry with your approach.

Answer (score 2):

try to guess the background density and move all to white:

```
convert -density 300 foo.pdf  -white-threshold 80% bar.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have openoffice.org installed, you can install the pdf-import plugin (I believe it is in the software center), and then open your pdf in openoffice.org writer, change the background, and save it again.

You can even create a hybrid pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

in ImageMagick:

1. file -> open -> foo.pdf -> import
2. select -> by color ->
3. second item in toolbar (dutch: bewerken) -> fill with BG-color
4. repeat 2 and 3 if necessary for other background colors
5. file -> print